# Google Sheets Conditionally format a range based on values from another range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a column/range of emails like:

- jschmoe@zzz.org
- vwilliams@zzz.org
- hpotter@zzz.org
- swilliams@zzz.org

and a column/range of names like:

- jschmoe
- vwilliams
- tbrady
- rdowneyjr
- caguilera
- swilliams

I'm trying highlight the emails column based on if it finds any substring name from the names column in any of the email columns' emails.

I've tried various variations of COUNTIF, but most of the examples I have found online are for excel and not specifically google sheets.

I've tried
`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("ScrubbedNames"), I4)`
and
`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("ScrubbedNames"), I4:I159)`

Where `ScrubbedNames` is the range of names without the email domain and I4 is the first email on the list, or I4:I159 is the entire list of emails

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am new to Stack Exchange and Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `countif()` function will by default do an *exact* match, and `jschmoe` does not exactly match `jschmoe@zzz.org`.

To get partial matches, use the `*` wildcard. In your use case, you apparently want to match usernames like `jschmoe` with email addresses like `jschmoe@zzz.org`. You can do that like this:

`=countif(indirect("ScrubbedNames"), I4 & "@*")`

The `ScrubbedNames` named range is wrapped in `indirect()`. That is only required because this is a *conditional formula custom formula rule* rather than a regular formula.